# "To operate the machine, it is not necessary to raise the bonnet."

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, soft-question

The quotation in the title is attributed to Frank Adams and appears in several places:

- In the preface of [2002, *[Operads in algebra, topology and physics](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=SURV-96-S)*]: "to operate the machine, it is not necessary to raise the bonnet (look under the hood)."
- In [Stasheff, 2004, *[What is ... an operad?](http://www.ams.org/notices/200406/what-is.pdf)*]: "to operate the machine, it is not necessary to raise the bonnet (look under the hood)."
- In footnote 4 of [Riehl, 2011, *[Algebraic model structures](http://nyjm.albany.edu/j/2011/17-10.html)*]: "to operate the machine, it is not necessary to raise the bonnet."

However, I have trouble finding any earlier appearances of the quote. I found something in that spirit in [Adams, 1978, *Infinite loop spaces*, §2.3]:

> Unfortunately, as I have hinted in §2.1, the construction and use of machines takes work. Therefore this chapter will be written as an essay in machine appreciation; it is not intended to qualify the reader for a mechanic's certificate.

**Question.** Does the quotation in the title appear in the writings of Frank Adams? Or was it a spoken remark that has been transmitted through folklore?

(I apologise for the non-mathematical question, but I thought MathOverflow would be the most likely place to find the answer.)

Comment: I think it would also be interesting to hear opinions on this quote.

Comment: Is it too late to suggest a new "ask-may" tag?

Comment: Vidit, that isn't a capital M meant is it?  I'm sure I heard Frank say that quote in a talk, but I can't remember when or where. I also couldn't find it in his "Infinite loop spaces", but that sure is still enjoyable reading. Let me just recommend it.

Comment: @petermay I have it on good authority that the jokes are excruciating!

Comment: Is that the book with an item "jokes" in the index?

Comment: Tom, yes it is, and Vidit is referring to the Math Review of Frank's book.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie I just checked and "jokes" also appears in the index of Ravenel's Nilpotence and Periodicity.